# Defining functions inside proof scope

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to prove that injective functions are left invertible in Coq. I've reached a point in my proof where my goal is an "exists" proposition. I want to define a function that uses terms from proof scope (types and functions I've intro'ed before) and then show the function to the "exists" goal. Here's what I wrote so far:

```coq
(* function composition *)
Definition fun_comp {A B C: Type} (f:A -> B) (g:B -> C) : A -> C :=
  fun a: A => g (f a).

Notation "g .o f" := (fun_comp f g) (at level 70).

Definition nonempty (A: Type) := exists a: A, a = a.

(* identity function for any given type *)
Definition fun_id (A: Type) := fun a: A => a.

(* left invertible *)
Definition l_invertible {A B: Type} (f: A -> B) :=
  exists fl:B->A, fl .o f = fun_id A.

Definition injective {A B: Type} (f: A -> B) :=
  forall a a':  A, f a = f a' -> a = a'.

(* is a given element in a function's image? *)
Definition elem_in_fun_image {A B: Type} (b: B) (f: A -> B) :=
  exists a: A, f a = b.

Theorem injective_is_l_invertible:
  forall (A B: Type) (f: A -> B), nonempty A /\ injective f -> l_invertible f.
Proof.
  intros A B f H.
  destruct H as [Hnempty Hinj].
  unfold l_invertible.
  unfold nonempty in Hnempty.
  destruct Hnempty as [a0].
  (* here would go my function definition and invoking "exists myfun" *)
```

Here's the function I'm trying to define:

```coq
Definition fL (b: B) := if elem_in_fun_image b f 
                        then f a 
                        else a0.
```

Here's what the proof window looks like:

```coq
 1 subgoal    
                                                    
A : Type
B : Type
f : A -> B
a0 : A
H : a0 = a0
Hinj : injective f

========================= (1 / 1)
                              
exists fl : B -> A, (fl .o f) = fun_id A
```

How do I do this? I'm very new to Coq so other comments and pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definition cannot be performed in the basic logic. You need to add in a few extra axioms:

```
(* from Coq.Logic.FunctionalExtensionality *)
functional_extensionality : forall A B (f g : A -> B),
  (forall x, f x = g x) -> f = g

(* from Coq.Logic.Classical *)
classic : forall P : Prop, P \/ ~ P

(* from Coq.Logic.ClassicalChoice *)
choice : forall (A B : Type) (R : A->B->Prop),
  (forall x : A, exists y : B, R x y) ->
   exists f : A->B, (forall x : A, R x (f x)).
```

The goal is to define a relation `R` that characterizes the left inverse that you want to construct.  The existentially quantified `f` will then be the inverse! You will need the `classic` axiom to show the precondition of `choice`, and you will need functional extensionality to show the equation that you want. I'll leave it as an exercise to find out what `R` needs to be and how to complete the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should start with the following line.

```
Require Import ClassicalChoice FunctionalEquality.
```

Because, as suggested by @arthur-azevedo-de-amorim, you will need these axioms.

Then, you should use `choice` with the relation "R y x" being
"f x = A or there is no element in A such whose image by f is y".

You will need the axiom `classic` to prove the existential statement that is required by `choice`:

```
assert (pointwise : forall y: B, exists x : A,
           f x = y \/ (forall x : A f x <> y)).
```

`choice` will give you an existential statement for a function that returns the value you want.  You only need to say that this function is the right one.  You can give a name to that function by typing `destruct (choice ... pointwise)` (you have to fill in the `...`).

You will have to prove an equality between two functions, but using the axiom `functional_extensionality`, you can reduce this problem to just proving that the two functions are equal on any `x`.

For that x,  just instantiate the characteristic property of the function (as produced by `destruct (choice ... pointwise)` with the
value `f x`.  There is a disjuction, but the right-hand side case is self-contradictory, because obviously `f x` is `f x` for some `x`.

For the left-hand side case, you will get an hypothesis of the form (I name the function produced by `(choice ... pointwise)` with the name `it`:

`f (it (f x)) = f x`

Here you can apply your injectivity assumption. to deduce that `it (f x) = x`.

This pretty much spells out the proof.  In my own, experiment, I used `classic`, `NNP`, `not_all_ex_not`, `functional_extensionality`, which are lemmas coming from `ClassicalChoice` of `FunctionalEquality`.